# sun.security.provider.certpathS .SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, node.js, maven, ssl-certificate, intellij-15

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.6:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project sok-wcm.ui.frontend: Could not download Node.js fr
om: https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.16.0/win-x64/node.exe: Could not download https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.16.0/win-x64/node.exe: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

Trying to do maven build but encountered the above error.

1.I have tried replacing my jdk security cacert folder with one of my team mates folder which is working for them. It didn't work for me.
I thought it was failing at getting npm packages, but it's actually not even getting node... so this is....

2.Configured USER Variable the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable for your user with the following information:

-Xmx512m -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=NONE -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=Windows-my -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=NONE -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT

3.Tried manually installing node using the link that is in the error message.

Comment: Any suggestions on this issue?